# Displaying new Texture2D as a RawTexture and using it for vertex displacement does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d, unity-webgl

It seems like creating Texture2Ds on runtime and modifying them with SetPixel should not be a problem in a WebGL build - but somehow I cannot manage to get it working. On the long run I want to modify vertex positions with a new Texture2D. 
When I noticed my approach did not work when building to WebGL I tried to display the texture as a RawTexture UI element - which is not an issue in the editor, but it is not working in WebGL either.

This is the code I use to create the new texture:

```
meshRenderer.material = Instantiate(meshRenderer.material);
texture = new Texture2D(textureSize, textureSize, TextureFormat.Alpha8, true);
meshRenderer.material.SetTexture("_TexDYN", texture);
rawImage.texture = texture;
```

In this example, textureSize is 64 as WebGL only supports power of two textures.
I use TextureFormat.Alpha8 because I only need one channel for my texture - but using the default TextureFormat does not work either.

This is the code for updating the texture:

```
texture.SetPixel(pixelUV.x, pixelUV.y, new Color(value, value, value, value));
texture.Apply();
```

Pretty basic stuff I thought - are there any restrictions for WebGL I'm not aware of?
Everything works perfectly in the Editor and Windows Build.

I'm using Unity 2020.3.19f1